# How start a JQuery inside PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I want to start a jquery (freeow plugin) when I got an error in e-mail input field form.

I'm checking some fields on the form and each error that I got I want to open an alert message.

I can do this using a button, like this...

```
<div id="freeow-tr" class="freeow freeow-top-right"></div>
<div id="freeow-br" class="freeow freeow-bottom-right"></div>

<div class="form-line-check">
    <input id="freeow-title" value="Freeow!" type="hidden" class="text" />
    <input id="freeow-error" value="0" type="hidden" />
    <input id="freeow-position" value="#freeow-tr" type="hidden" />
    <input id="freeow-style" value="smokey" type="hidden" />
    <input id="freeow-message" value="Error message..." type="hidden" />
</div>

<div class="form-line">
    <input id="freeow-show" type="button" value="Click to Freeow!" />
</div>
```

How do this without the button? Inside the PHP code.

```
if ($erro == "0") {
    if(filter_var($email01, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $erro = "0";
        } else {
               echo "<div id=\"freeow-tr\" class=\"freeow freeow-top-right\"></div> ";
               echo "<div id=\"freeow-br\" class=\"freeow freeow-bottom-right\"></div> ";
               echo "<div class=\"form-line-check\"> ";
               echo "<input id=\"freeow-title\"        value=\"Freeow!\"     type=\"hidden\"     class=\"text\" /> ";
               echo "<input id=\"freeow-error\"        value=\"0\"           type=\"hidden\" /> ";
               echo "<input id=\"freeow-position\"     value=\"#freeow-tr\"  type=\"hidden\" /> ";
               echo "<input id=\"freeow-style\"        value=\"smokey\"      type=\"hidden\" /> ";
               echo "<input id=\"freeow-message\"      value=\"Error message...\"    type=\"hidden\" /> ";
               echo "</div> ";

               $erro = "1";
    }
}
```

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with this? You submit a form, you get an HTML document back. The if condition will vary what that document consists of.

Comment: When the form is submit php check some fields, like e-mail, and if there are an error I want to display the jquery alarm.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to create a javascript function

function mensagem01() {

```
var title, message, opts, container;
title = $("#freeow-title").val();
message = $("#freeow-message").val();
message = 'E-mail not in database...';

opts = {};
opts.classes = [$("#freeow-style").val()];

opts.prepend = false;
opts.classes.push("error");
opts.autoHide = false;
opts.classes.push("slide");
opts.hideStyle = { opacity: 0, left: "400px" };
opts.showStyle = { opacity: 1, left: 0       };

container = $("#freeow-position").val();
$(container).freeow(title, message, opts);
}
```

1. HTML code need to have the freeow definitions

   ```
   <div id="freeow-tr" class="freeow freeow-top-right"></div>      
   <div id="freeow-br" class="freeow freeow-bottom-right"></div>   
   <div class="form-line-check"> 
   <input id="freeow-title" value="Lembrou?" type="hidden" class="text" /> 
   <input id="freeow-error" value="0" type="hidden" /> 
   <input id="freeow-position" value="#freeow-tr" type="hidden" /> 
   <input id="freeow-style" value="smokey" type="hidden" />
   <input id="freeow-message" value="message field must be empty" type="hidden" /> 
   </div>
   ```
2. Inside PHP code

You need to include the javascript code to call the javascript function message

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">  $(document).write(mensagem01());  </script> \n";
```

When the php is executed the javascript write the document, which contains the call to the freeow message.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve will is best done with [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and some more logic than you have in your code.

1. You want to catch the form submit with jQuery. Using `event.prefentDefault()` you can stop the form from submitting. Then, you want to AJAX your [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to the server.
2. In your PHP script, you do your validation. If it succeeds, return something (for example, a JSON object) that tells your front end that the validation was a success. If not, you want an object that describes what exactly is failing.
3. From front end, you check to see if the validation was a success (do whatever), or not (show freeow)